# Error while installing "ros-indigo-ros-controllers"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, wish to use GAZEBO as a simulator, with p3DX vehicle. and following steps given [here](https://bcrlab.wordpress.com/ros-gazebo-p3at/).

While Installing Additional ROS Packages mentioned in step 6.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-controllers
```

i am getting error, which can be visualize at the end of output below.

```
bcr-lab@bcrlab-HP-Z800-Workstation:~/catkin_ws$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-controllers
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
ros-indigo-diff-drive-controller ros-indigo-effort-controllers
ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller
ros-indigo-forward-command-controller ros-indigo-gripper-action-controller
ros-indigo-imu-sensor-controller ros-indigo-joint-state-controller
ros-indigo-joint-trajectory-controller ros-indigo-position-controllers
ros-indigo-rqt-joint-trajectory-controller ros-indigo-velocity-controllers

The following NEW packages will be installed:
ros-indigo-diff-drive-controller ros-indigo-effort-controllers
ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller
ros-indigo-forward-command-controller ros-indigo-gripper-action-controller
ros-indigo-imu-sensor-controller ros-indigo-joint-state-controller
ros-indigo-joint-trajectory-controller ros-indigo-position-controllers
ros-indigo-ros-controllers ros-indigo-rqt-joint-trajectory-controller
ros-indigo-velocity-controllers
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.0 kB/682 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,601 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller amd64 0.9.3-0trusty-20160627-235716-0700
403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller/ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller_0.9.3-0trusty-20160627-235716-0700_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Unable to understand what to do. Please help. I am new to ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243040/error-while-installing-%22ros-indigo-ros-controllers%22/) by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just tested this, but the following doesn't result in a `403` error for me:

```
$ wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller/ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller_0.9.3-0trusty-20160627-235716-0700_amd64.deb
--2016-09-04 11:29:40--  http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller/ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller_0.9.3-0trusty-20160627-235716-0700_amd64.deb
Resolving packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)... 140.211.166.134, 64.50.233.100, 64.50.236.52
Connecting to packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)|140.211.166.134|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 34016 (33K)
Saving to: `ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller_0.9.3-0trusty-20160627-235716-0700_amd64.deb'

100%[==================================================================================================>] 34,016       201K/s   in 0.2s

2016-09-04 11:29:42 (201 KB/s) - `ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller_0.9.3-0trusty-20160627-235716-0700_amd64.deb' saved [34016/34016]
```

Are you behind a proxy by any chance?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2016-09-04**:
yes i am behind a proxy.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-04**:
Does the proxy need authentication? Can you install other pkgs (non-ROS)? What is the output of

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller/ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller_0.9.3-0trusty-20160627-235716-0700_amd64.deb
```

On your machine?

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2016-09-04**:
yes it need authentication, but i am able to install other ros packages,

and this is the outcome for your instruction,

```
Connecting to 192.168.3.10:3128... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2016-09-04 16:13:52 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-04**:
Well I can only think that *something* is making your proxy server refuse to let you download the `ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller` package. Perhaps you can take this up with your network administrator(s)? Please do report back if/when you get this resolved.

**Comment by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on 2016-09-16**:
this was just an issue with proxy.